# How to put the result from the SQL-query in a dropdown?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I use const

```
mysql = require('mysql2')
```

and query my db with

```
connection.query(query, function(err, result) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, result);
});
```

this works well enough, I receive the results. However, I then try to pass the results to express with

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    (sql code goes here), store it in result
      res.render('search', {
        dropdowns: [{
            name: 'Name1',
            title: 'Name1',
            options: result
            ...
            }
```

I get a dropdown list with the correct number of entries, however they are all empty/"" (.).

If I use console.log it says

> [15:52:07] [log] [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]".

I have also tried to make javascript objects and JSON.stringify these with no luck. If I hard code the SQL query results it works.. The options should look like

```
{"value":"foo","title":"foo!"}.
```

EDIT:  Here is what the SQL-code looks like. Where render is below, res.render is inserted.

```
function getMessage(query, callback) {
    doQuery(query, function (err, result) {
        if(err || !result.length) return callback('error or no results');
        callback(null, result);
    });
}

function doQuery(query, callback) {
    connection.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, result);
    });
};

getMessage(combinedQ, function(err, result){
    maxAvgift=result[0].maxAvgift;
    minAvgift=result[0].minAvgift;
    maxRum=result[0].maxRum;
    minRum=result[0].minRum;
    maxArea=result[0].maxArea;
    minArea=result[0].minArea;
    maxPris=result[0].maxPris;
    minPris=result[0].minPris;

    getMessage(disctinctLan, function(err, result){
      createJSON(result, lanList);
    });
    getMessage(disctinctObjekttyp, function(err, result){
      createJSON(result, objekttypList);
    });

    getMessage(testQ, function(err, result){
      console.log(result);
      createResultArray(result);

      render()
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please include the sql code?

Comment: Alright I solved it with some help of a friend! I create Objects and set object.value=result.res put all the hits of the queries in a list. In res.render I then set options: objectList.